# Error running hello world on node.js

Tags: macos, node.js

I am on OSX and installed node from the website.

When I tried running basic

```
console.log('Hello World')
```

it's giving me following error

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `'Hello world''
```

Please let me know how do I proceed.

I tried re-installing node from [Node Github installation](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installation) and if I try to check version of node or npm, I can see them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Terminal is just a window running Bash (by default) - you are expecting Bash to suddenly understand JavaScript just by installing node.js on your system. You must first switch from Bash to Node by typing `node` and then you can start executing JavaScript commands.

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> twice to exit.

Answer (score 1):

You have to run: `node yourfilename.js`

Or if you want to Access to The REPL: `node -i`

Comment: it's not in file. I'm just running it in Terminal

Comment: You can't execute code directly from The terminal. You have to put your code into a file and launch it, or run code interactively using the REPL